# how to add navigation controller and tab bar controller within viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing one application which includes view controller because my first two pages content only view not tab-bar.after that i have created run time tab-bar controller using this code

```
           UIViewController *viewcontroller1 = [[viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller1" bundle:nil];
            viewcontroller1.title = @"sometext";
            viewcontroller1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];

            UIViewController *viewcontroller2 = [[viewcontroller2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller2" bundle:nil];
            viewcontroller2.title = @"sometext";
            viewcontroller2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];

            tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller1" bundle:nil];
            tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewcontroller1,viewcontroller2, nil];
            tbc.selectedViewController = viewcontroller1;

            ////    NSLog(@"Selected index = %d of %d", tbc.selectedIndex, [tbc.viewControllers count]);
            [self presentModalViewController:tbc animated:NO];
```

it is working properly but in my second view i want tab-bar controller and navigation-controller both.
so in viewcontroller2 i have implemented code like that it's giving me navigation controller but it's hiding tab-bar controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[viewcontroller2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller2" bundle:nil]];
    [self presentModalViewController:nvc animated:NO];
    [nvc release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

so please help me what to i do so i can get both tab-bar controller & navigation-controller in this viewcontroller2.??
please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new class for tabbar and in UI Design time you can add navigation controller as tab and set view in navigation controller. Whenever you want add tabbar controller in that page create object of tabbarcontroller class object and add it on view.

Comment: do you have any sample code about implementing that kind of you have answered & like i asked question. please give me more brief about your answer.

Comment: i am working on it will provide you. just for my info for iPhone or for iPad?

Comment: i am working on iphone... if you will provide me sample than it will very helpful for me but make sure this sample will satisfy my question.

Comment: can you send me mail at my email id?

Comment: you don't mention your mail id?

Comment: sorry my email id id : addonblackberry2010@gmail.com

Comment: i didn't get your mail to my email id:addonblackberry2010@gmail.com please make sure you have sent it to this id. thanks for reply

Comment: send you again. please check now.

Comment: thanks i get your mail but i think it's not satisfying my condition means i asked question.